# A more specific term/compound word for an image that enumerates and shows the parts of something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a more specific term for something like this:

[image: Diagram of a heart]

*Diagram* is the first thing that comes to mind, but I find it vague for there are different types of diagrams.

I also thought of *anatomy*, but I don't want to limit it to living things.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the more generic term used in technical documentation (not the answer you're looking for, but a clarification), is *figure*.

Answer (score 1):

That's an illustration of human heart.

> **Illustration:** Something that serves to illustrate, such as a picture or diagram that helps make something clear or attractive. [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illustration)

Answer (score 0):

*Diagram* came to me too. But if you want to apply it to non-living things also then how about ***cutaway*** ?

> *cutaway* : a diagram or drawing with some external parts left out to reveal the interior.

Other synonyms that fits the usage are:

blueprint, chart, design, figure, game, layout, outline.